# Angular control value accessor with existing validation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to implement a custom Angular component that acts as a `ControlValueAccessor` and accepts and uses validation directives?

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<input-component [(ngModel)]="someValue" required max="10"></input-component>
<input-component [(ngModel)]="otherValue" email min="10"></input-component>
```

And the component itself would essentially have this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue.prop">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue.otherProp">
```

Each of the inputs should be validated separately with the validators provided to the component.

But it would have other stuff wrapped around that `input` which is why it warrants its own component.

Is there a way I can have my component "accept" the validator directives and apply them when it wants?

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

4.2.0-beta.0 (2017-05-04)

Features

forms: introduce min and max validators ([#15813](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15813)) ([81925fa](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/81925fa))